# Preventing blazors smooth page scroll when navigating to new page

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, asp.net-core-5.0

I have an app (SPA website) with infinitely scrollable **feed**. Upon reaching the bottom of the page - a new set of data is loaded.

The problem is when navigating away from 1 page to another - instead of switching context instantaneously - `blazor` smoothly scrolls to 0 scroll position on the new page.

This causes all sorts of issues.

- when switching from feed (where I scrolled a bit) to other page - this also triggers the feed end of page data load function
- when switching from other page (where I scrolled a bit) to feed - the `blazor` again scrolls to 0 position smoothly, AND also it triggers the data load function because at the time of page load - the scroll position is already considered to be on the bottom of the new page..

What I have tried doing is implementing `IAsyncDisposable` and/or `IDisposable`, but it seems like `Dispose` methods are not guaranteed to be executed BEFORE reaching the new page!
In my tests I was trying to set the window scroll position to 0 before leaving the page:

```
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _data?.Clear();
        _data= null;
        ((IJSInProcessRuntime)_jsRuntime).InvokeVoid($"setScrollPosition", 0);
    }
```

js

```
    function setScrollPosition(scrollPosition) {
        window.scrollTo({ top: scrollPosition, left: 0, behavior: 'instant' })
    }
```

This does not work because new page is initialized before old page is disposed of.

The code responsible for data load when bottom of the **feed** page is reached is:

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        InitEndOfPageDetection();

        await LoadMoreDataAsync();
    }

    private async Task LoadMoreDataAsync()
    {
        var response = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<<MoreData>($"Feed/GetMoreData");
        var data = response.Data;
        _data.AddRange(data);
        _isEndOfPageReached = data.Count == 0;
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private DotNetObjectReference<ViewFeed> objRef;

    public void InitEndOfPageDetection()
    {
        objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);

        ((IJSInProcessRuntime)JSRuntime).InvokeVoid("initEndOfPageDetector", objRef);
    }

    object _lock = new object();
    bool _isEndOfPageReached = false;

    [JSInvokable]
    public void EndOfPageReached()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_isEndOfPageReached)
            {
                return;
            }

            _isEndOfPageReached = true;
            LoadMoreDataAsync();
        }
    }
```

js

```
    function isEndOfPage() {
        var tresholdPx = 300;
        if ((window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset) >= document.body.offsetHeight - tresholdPx) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function initEndOfPageDetector(instance) {
        window.onscroll = function (ev) {
            if (isEndOfPage()) {
                instance.invokeMethodAsync('EndOfPageReached');
            }
        };
    }
```

As mentioned  - unfortunately the contents of new pages are loaded BEFORE the previous page is disposed, so my scroll to 0 position hack is not working.. **note: I have somewhat simplified the code for demo purpose. Request query parameters are missing etc.**

I would expect the switching to new page to happen immediately, without scrolling or any kinds of additional hacks. Is there a way to accomplish this natively in `Blazor`? Is this how other SPA frameworks (such as `Angular` and `ReactJs`) are behaving by default when switching page contexts?

I am using `.Net 5` and `Blazor WASM` template.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="height:100vh; overflow-y:scroll;"` to `<app></app>` tag in _Host.cshtml.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).